Get call graph / path of C with function pointer
I have a C codebase with function calls made through function pointers. I tried using LLVM AST and IR with Python to generate a function call graph, but handling the function pointer calls requires significantly more effort. Do you have any recommendations for achieving this more easily?

In general it is impossible to know what is behind pointers at compile time. Unless the particular usage is trivial, in which case it should be replaced by direct calls anyway.

You need to analyse the systematics behind this, there is no easy way around this.

@ close voters, though we do not provide help for debugging specific code, conceptual debugging questions do clearly belong to software engineering. This question is quite broad, of course, and might be closed with "needs more focus", but not as "off topic"

You have to run the program then generate a backtrace. Especially in C, there are all sorts of ways to "smuggle" pointers around untraceably, so producing a fully static callgraph is impossible.

The problem in making such a call graph, is double:

when calling via the function pointer, most of the time there are several possible callees, each with a different subgraph
it is not possible at compile time to always determine which of the functions may be called.

However, assuming you have a graph notation to show the alternative calls, an elaborate tool could in many circumstances determine the possible candidates through a combination of different techniques:

Constant propagation techniques:
  void foo() { printf("foo\n");}
  void bar() { printf("bar\n");}
  ...
  void (*f)(); 

  f = foo;   
  f();      // by constant propagation we know it's foo


branch analysis to identify possible sets of callees:
  int r = rand()%2; 
  if (r%2)
     f = bar;
  else f= foo; 
  f(); // we know it's foo or bar


making a set out of an array:
  void (*t[])()={foo,bar,zoo}; 
  ...
  for (int i=0; i<2; i++) 
      t[i]();    // it's one of the three 


if such array is initialised by assignment of individual items,  the candidate list would just grow with every possible function address assigne to one of the elements (since there might be overwrites, the candidate list might be larger than what known at runtime).

other value propagation techniques. This is not an easy task, since the table could be provided as a pointer argument, and some global analysis (like global optimiser do) might be required.


The driving idea for the approach described above, is that the function pointers use directly or indirectly a function address that was propagated in the expressions.  Unfortunately, implementing this algorithm is quite challenging and may not match your expectation of "more easy", as it should take account not only arrays of function pointers, but also arrays of struct containing a function pointer member, which is a quite common use-case) and some other hurdles.
It is moreover not always possible to narrow down the candidate callees,  for example when an external third party function provides the function pointers, or when dangerous pointer arithmetics are done:
f = bar +2; // ouch! 
f(); 

and of course if the code itself does some forbidden things, like going out of bounds for arrays or using uninitialised arrays.
Edit: Apparently, googling around, there seem to be already quite some research work on the topic (e.g. here or here, where it is claimed that it was already embedded in a proprietary tool, and this more recent article).
Edit 2: There is also egypt, a tool that takes the reverse approach, looking for function adresses used in the code to identify possible subsequent calls via function pointers.  It does not produce accurate call graph in this regard (since the function pointer taken in one function may be used somewhere else), but at least highlights functions that may be called indirectly.

A function pointer can be used to call functions which do not exist at build time in the source code. On Linux you can use dlopen(3) with dlsym(3) and this paper shows a concrete example (some C++ code generated at runtime and compiled to a dlopened plugin containing new dlsym-ed functions).
With libraries like GNU lightning or asmjit or libgccjit you can generate function machine code at runtime (which would depend on some prior runtime input, perhaps using partial evaluation techniques).
Dynamic machine code generation is used in the V8 engine so used in most modern web browsers.
The RefPerSys (open source) inference engine project is using such (machine code generation) techniques and so could Bigloo and so does SBCL (a Common Lisp open source implementation).
Even in a program not generating or adding new code computing (at build or compile time, not run time) the possible values of a function pointer is impossible (equivalent to the Halting problem) or very difficult (use abstract interpretation if you want to try simple cases).
However, consider using Frama-C to analyze  your C (or C++) code.

As other answers have stated, this is very hard (in general, undecidable) to do statically, unless your codebase's use of function pointers is particularly static. Fortunately, highly dynamic codebases are rare. So depending on your codebase, and what you need the callgraph for, it might be enough to do something simpler.
The easiest type of incomplete tracking is just doing it dynamically. You can just use a profiler that can generate a call graph, and running a comprehensive test suite or a fuzzer to get as much coverage as possible. This only tracks what actually gets executed during the profiling, and there's no guarantee you'll get 100% of the possibilities, so you may have false negatives, but then again, depending on what you need, this may be enough.
If you need something more complete (but potentially too conservative), you could do a simple conservative type-based analysis. I will assume C because it's much harder to do for C++.
Consider the following code:
typedef void *(*allocator)(size_t);

void *malloc(size_t);
void *alloc_safe(size_t);

/* in another file */
static void *alloc_from_temp_arena(size_t);

Whenever a function pointer of type allocator (or equivalent) is called, any function of this type (globally, remember to include static functions and functions from other files) may be the target.
This incomplete tracking is overly conservative, and may report false positives for calls which can never actually happen. Also, it doesn't really work if you have loaded dynamic modules, JITs or otherwise code outside your analysis. But if your codebase doesn't do any of these, it may be enough.
You could even combine data from a profiler with a conservative type-based analysis, and say that any calls observed by the profiler are certainly possible, any calls not yielded by the type-based analysis are certainly impossible, and any calls returned by the type-based analysis but not seen by the profiler are potentially possible. This last set will likely be small, and could maybe be hand-checked, if necessary, or the uncertainty just indicated in the output, if that's useful to you.
In the end, it depends on what you need this call graph for. You don't have to solve the Halting Problem just to make a visualisation, for example.
